# Flickering on scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to make a piece of text disappear when the users scrolls down, and reappear when the user goes back to the top. It has succeeded in a somewhat rudimentary, far from smooth way, yet I notice the text flickers at a certain point in a very distracting way and I'm not sure what the problem is or how to fix it.

```js
var $win = $(window)
var $doc = $(document)

  $win.scroll(function(e) {
    scrollEffects();
  });

function scrollEffects() {
  var limit = 85;
  var scrolled = $win.scrollTop();
  if ($doc.scrollTop() >= limit) {
    $(".intro").addClass('inactive');
    //$('#banner-contents').css('opacity', 1 - (scrolled * .00280));
    // console.log('scrolled');
  } else {
    $(".intro").removeClass('inactive');
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
  background: tomato;
}

.nav {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

.intro {
  color: $black;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.inactive {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav">
  <p class="intro"> This is some text that should disappear without flickering</p>
  
  Other text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting an element to `display: none` will make the layout of your document be rendered as if the element was not part of it.

So, at the moment you add the `inactive`-class to the paragraph, the height of the parent nav-div changes (because `p.intro` is gone, so to say). This of course also affects the scroll position, which is now below `limit` again. This in turn removes the `inactive`-class on p, which changes your layout again ... and so on. This is the reason for the flickering.

Use `visibility` instead of `display`:

```
.inactive {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

EDIT:

If you want to gradually decrease the height of the paragraph you could use css transitions:

```
.intro {
  color: $black;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 2rem; /* or something more appropriate */
  transition: max-height 1s ease;
}

.inactive {
   max-height: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: max-height 1s ease;
}
```

Or you could tie the paragraph's height to the scroll position:

```
$('.intro').css('max-height', Math.max(0, 30 - (scrolled * .28)));
```

Of course in this case you need to set `max-height: 30px;` (or some size that fits your needs) and `overflow: hidden;` on the `intro`-class. Also, you then wouldn't need the `inactive`-class.

Comment: I understand what the problem is, however, i can't use visibility: hidden; because I need the height of the element to disappear as well. The goal is to have a navbar with an introductory text that will disappear once the user scrolls, leaving only the necessarily links to navigate through the website.

Comment: @slotstartslotend This is not what you asked. Please be more precise in your question. I've edited my answer with two suggestions for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've used the first method and it works perfectly (and a lot smoother) than my previous attempt. However, if I use longer text (3-4 lines) it will still flicker at a certain moment in the scrolling action and get "stuck" (it will continue to flicker until i change the scroll position). Is is possible that it is still recalculating the height and/or perhaps for longer pieces of text another approach should be used?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Could you set up an example where we can see the flickering?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried to reproduce the problem but I can't either. It only happens on one page even though it should be the same as the other pages. I've tried to delete all other elements around it, copy and paste, recreate it on JS fiddle....It only happens on this one page. It makes no sense, life makes no sense. Thank you for you time and I will try to be more clear on future posts.

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the problem. I would say it's definitely connected to changes in document height. I couldn't reproduce it before because there was no content in the body, but now I've added a few paragraphs of text and the flickering is present again: https://jsfiddle.net/fb9x47zc/